# Can I suppress selected input before the application's main loop?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, mousewheel, mouse-hook

As part of my Visual Studio utilities add-in [SamTools](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:SamTools:Features), I have a mouse input routine that catches Ctrl+MouseWheel and sends a pageup/pagedown command to the active text window. Visual Studio 2010 added a new "feature" that uses that gesture for zoom in/out (barf). Currently, my add-in does send the scrolling command, but Visual Studio still changes the font size because I'm not eating the input.

I set my hook with a call to `SetWindowsHookEx`. Here's the callback code. **My question is:** is the best way to prevent Visual Studio from handling the Ctrl+MouseWheel input as a zoom command to simply *not* call `CallNextHookEx` when I get a mouse wheel event with the Ctrl key down?

(Please bear in mind this is some *old* code of mine.) :)

```
private IntPtr MouseCallback(int code, UIntPtr wParam, ref MOUSEHOOKSTRUCTEX lParam)
{
    try
    {
        // the callback runs twice for each action - this is the latch
        if (enterHook)
        {
            enterHook = false;
            if (code >= 0)
            {
                int x = lParam.mstruct.pt.X;
                int y = lParam.mstruct.pt.Y;

                uint action = wParam.ToUInt32();
                switch (action)
                {
                case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                    OnMouseWheel(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.None, 0, x, y, ((short)HIWORD(lParam.mouseData)) / (int)WHEEL_DELTA));
                    break;

                default:
                    // don't do anything special
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            enterHook = true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // can't let an exception get through or VS will crash
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(mouseHandle, code, wParam, ref lParam);
}
```

And here's the code that executes in response to the `MouseWheel` event:

```
void mouse_enhancer_MouseWheel( object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e )
{
    try
    {
        if ( Keyboard.GetKeyState( System.Windows.Forms.Keys.ControlKey ).IsDown && Connect.ApplicationObject.ActiveWindow.Type == vsWindowType.vsWindowTypeDocument )
        {
            int clicks = e.Delta;
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                Connect.ApplicationObject.ExecuteCommand( "Edit.ScrollPageDown", "" );
            }
            else
            {
                Connect.ApplicationObject.ExecuteCommand( "Edit.ScrollPageUp", "" );
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException )
    {
        // this occurs if ctrl+wheel is activated on a drop-down list. just ignore it.
    }
}
```

PS: SamTools is open source (GPL) - you can download it from the link and the source is in the installer.

PSS: Ctrl+[+] and Ctrl+[-] are better for zooming. Let Ctrl+MouseWheel scroll (the vastly more commonly used command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988(VS.85).aspx), it's possible to toss mouse messages that you process. Here's the recommendation:

> If nCode is less than zero, the hook
>   procedure must return the value
>   returned by CallNextHookEx.
>
> If nCode is greater than or equal to
>   zero, and the hook procedure did not
>   process the message, it is highly
>   recommended that you call
>   CallNextHookEx and return the value it
>   returns; otherwise, other applications
>   that have installed WH_MOUSE hooks
>   will not receive hook notifications
>   and may behave incorrectly as a
>   result. If the hook procedure
>   processed the message, it may return a
>   nonzero value to prevent the system
>   from passing the message to the target
>   window procedure.

In other words, if your mouse callback ends up using the mouse message, you don't have to call the next `CallNextHookEx` -- just return a nonzero value and (in theory, at least) the mouse movement should get swallowed.  If that doesn't work the way you want, comment and we can iterate.

BTW, another possible alternative: it's possible that VS's mapping to the mouse wheel shows up in the Tools...Customize... UI, just like key mappings do.  In that case, you could simply remap your add-in's commands instead of working at the hook level. But it's also posible (likely?) that this gesture is hard-coded.

Comment: Unfortunately mouse commands don't show in the customize options.